# Pass option to cmake for future option to crosscompilation (CROSS_COMPILE)

Tags: makefile, cmake, cross-compiling, cmakelists-options

```
IF(UNIX)
    # CROSS COMPILATION! ON/OFF
    #SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /home/username/projects/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc)
    #SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/username/projects/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-g++)
    #SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /home/username/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc)
    #SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/username/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++)
```

here is what I do now for cross-compilation. I want to add option to run it alike that:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=~/projects/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-
```

and if I do not path CROSS_COMPILE to make (not to cmake) it must use system defaults so cmake must path this option to makefile. How can I make it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Buildroot generates a CMake toolchain file for you. Depending on your Buildroot, it might be directly in the `output` directory, or in `output/host/usr/share/buildroot`. The file is named `toolchainfile.cmake`. Then to build your CMake applications, do:

`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/buildroot/output/host/usr/share/buildroot/toolchainfile.cmake`

This file contains all the definitions of the cross-compiler paths, pkg-config environment variables, headers and libraries location, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest method, do this:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER $(CROSS_COMPILE)g++)
```

When the CROSS_COMPILE variable is passed to make, it will be substituted with the cross compiler path.

Now, the proper way. Ideally, the CROSS_COMPILE variable should be defined when CMake is run as it is meant to be cross-platform. Using the first solution could break if other CMake generators are used.

This can be done as:

```
IF(UNIX)
    SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILE}g++)
```

Then define the variable:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCROSS_COMPILE=~/projects/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-
```

In this case, CMake will generate proper build files, based on whether CROSS_COMPILE is defined or not.

Comment: Thank you but it's not what I want. and some bug here : ~/projects/buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-;g++: No such file or directory

Comment: I want to pass CROSS_COMPILE option to make (to makefile)

Comment: I edited the answer. But the first option might still give you a linker error. CMake is not supposed to use generator specific stuff like what you're trying to do. Passing the compiler variable via make to a CMake generated makefile should not be done. You should define the cross compiler when generating makefiles through CMake. The second option should work now.

Comment: that's sad. but thank you for providing this variant I will try to use it.